# How to get a 7x7 matrix numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to get a 7x7 matrix from my numpy array.

```
np.shape(y)
```

> (1, 7, 7, 32)

```
np.shape(y[0][:][:][:])
```

> (7, 7, 32)

```
np.shape(y[0][:][:][0])
```

> (7, 32)

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you want `y[0,:,:,0]`

Comment: How can this ever be 7x7 if there are `7*7*32` elements? Do you want a mean value?

Comment: @yatu that works, thanks!

Comment: Regarding "what am I doing wrong?":    In y[0][:][:][:] you apply a single bracket 4 times, and each time it acts only on the first coordinate of the result of the previous expression. So  y[0] is (7,7,32), then y[0][:] and y[0][:][:] are the same object and leave the shape unchanged. And then y[0][:][:][0] is a slice of  (7,7,32) at 0 of the first coordinate, so (7,32).

Comment: Can you show the expected outcome given an actual array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably thinking by analogy: "To get element `i, j, k, l` I can do

```
y[i][j][k][l]
```

if these indices are scalars, so why not for more general things like slices?"

The difference and reason why scalars work while slices don't is that scalar indexing removes dimensions, while slicing does not, so with `y[i]` having consumed the first dimension `[j]` targets the remaining first, i.e.the former second which is what you want. By contrast, `y[:]` leaves the first dimension in place, so the second and all following indexing operations mistarget.

This is only one of many reasons you should when dealing with multidimensional arrays virtually always prefer `y[ind1, ind2, ind3, etc.]` over `y[ind1][ind2][ind3][etc.]` be these indices scalars, slices or arrays.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot upvote for komark, please do it for me